# Add extra kernel to a CNN layer while maintaining the weights learned for the other kernels

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a simple feed forward conv neural network on the cifar10 dataset. After running a few epochs, I want to increase the kernel count in the 2nd conv layer from 16 to some number k.

How do I do this while keeping the trained weights for the other kernels and layers in the model intact?

```
def conv_layer(inp, fltrs):
    inp = Conv2D(filters = fltrs, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, padding = 'valid')(inp)
    inp = BatchNormalization()(inp)
    inp = Dropout(0.25)(inp)
    inp = Activation('relu')(inp)
    return inp

inp = Input(shape = (32, 32, 3))

x0 = conv_layer(inp, 8)
x1 = conv_layer(x0, 16)
x2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size= 2, strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)(x1)
x3 = conv_layer(x2, 32)
x4 = conv_layer(x3, 48)
x5 = conv_layer(x4, 64)
x6 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size= 2, strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)(x5)
x7 = Flatten()(x6)
x8 = Dense(512)(x7)
x9 = BatchNormalization()(x8)
x10 = Dropout(0.25)(x9)
x11 = Activation('relu')(x10)
x12 = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x11)


model = Model(inputs = [inp], outputs = [x12])
```

Comment: You can create a second model with the second set of params and then copy the weights layer by layer from the first to the second model.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @PedroMarques, even i thought of doing that, but it might be a rather slow piece of code. Do you know of a better way?

Comment: @spadarian, I wanted to see how network behaves when it perturbed slightly by adding an extra kernel.

Comment: Do you want to add an extra kernel and keep training the model? or just add an extra kernel with random weights?

Comment: @spadarian, Not sure yet. I may want to possibly resume training after adding the kernel.